# Swatch Internet Time for article timestamps

Tags: timestamp

The date and time when the article was published is shown below the article title.

How do I show [Swatch Internet Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time) there instead of local time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `'B'` as the format for `the_date()` and/or `the_time()` to generate Swatch Internet Time format.

If you're modifying a theme, just find the references to `the_date()` and/or `the_time()` in the template files and change the value of the `format` parameter.

If you're creating a plugin, you can hook into the `get_the_date` and/or `get_the_time` filters.

Comment: You need to put this in Settings > General > Time Format.

Comment: Also, set the time zone to UTC or it won't work!